# while loop condition not working 7

Tags: c

my problem is the while loop. While entering any code in the array, it continues to loop. i know its simple but i think the while loop condition is incorrect. Please help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[25]={
      4756,9870,5867,5241,2805,
      5490,4536,3458,3490,5666,1604,3045,1267,5766,
      2233,2938 ,3425,1837,6890,1029,7930,9348,2389,7689,3847
   },b;

   printf("\t\t\t ADABPO ENGINEERING\n");
   while(b!=a[25])
   {
      printf("Please enter your ID: ");
      scanf("%d",& b);
      if(b==a[0])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Ah-Fong Wan!");
      else if(b==a[1])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Aisac!");   
      else if(b==a[2])    
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Alsong!");          
      else  if(b==a[3])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Ayassamy!");
      else if(b==a[4])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Balkins!");   
      else  if(b==a[5])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Bilbo!");               

      // ...

      else 
      {
         printf("Unable to identify,please try again!!\n");    
      }
   }  
   getch();
}
```

Comment: You don't have 26 items in the array. If the size is 25, they indexed from 0 (included) to 24 (included).

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Add `\n` at end of every `printf` format string. Test the result of `scanf`. Use the debugger (`gdb`)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

```
while(b!=a[25])
```

1. When the execution of the program reaches the loop,`b` is not initialized.
2. `a[25]` is not  a valid location that you can use.

To fix the first problem change the `while` loop to a `do...while` loop. the `do...while` loop executes the body first, and then checks the condition, thus executing the body at least once and OTOH, the `while` loop checks the condition first and then executes the body of the loop,if it is true.

To fix the second problem, I guess you wanted `a[24]` there. This is because the valid array locations start from `a[0]` and end at `a[24]` not `a[25]` because array indices start from 0 not 1.

So, your program will look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[25]={
      4756,9870,5867,5241,2805,
      5490,4536,3458,3490,5666,1604,3045,1267,5766,
      2233,2938 ,3425,1837,6890,1029,7930,9348,2389,7689,3847
   },b;

   printf("\t\t\t ADABPO ENGINEERING\n");
   do
   {
      printf("Please enter your ID: ");
      scanf("%d",&b);
      if(b==a[0])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Ah-Fong Wan!\n");
      else if(b==a[1])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Aisac!\n");   
      else if(b==a[2])    
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Alsong!\n");          
      else  if(b==a[3])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Ayassamy!\n");
      else if(b==a[4])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Balkins!\n");   
      else  if(b==a[5])
         printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Bilbo!\n");               

      // ...

      else 
      {
         printf("Unable to identify,please try again!!\n");    
      }
   }while(b!=a[24]);  
   getch();
   return 0;//main returns an int
}
```

Note that you will face many problems when a user enters a character instead of a number for the `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array a[25], elements will be ranging from a[0] through a[24]. So there is no element called a[25] in your array.

Actually what you mean by the comparison b != a[25]?

In your case, it is better to use a do while loop so that loop will be executed atleast once, then it will check for conditions.

```
do {
    ...........
    ............
}while(condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the rest of the answers telling you to replace the while loop with a do-while loop, and also take note of the array index issue you have.

Then define exactly when you want the loop to end. By looking at your code I suppose you might want it to end when the user enters one of those numbers (any one of them, not just a[24]). If this is the case, you have to write the condition some other way, as it would not be feasible to write it as:

```
...
while(b != a[0] && b != a[1] && ... && b != a[24]);
```

One idea migth be to have a boolean flag that is set when the entered value is one of the expected values:

```
bool validIdFound = false;
do {
    ...
    if (b == a[0]) {
        validIdFound = true;
    }

    ...
} while(!validIdFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
 int a[25]={ 4756,9870,5867,5241,2805,
  5490,4536,3458,3490,5666,1604,3045,1267,5766,
  2233,2938 ,3425,1837,6890,1029,7930,9348,2389,7689,3847},b;

printf("\t\t\t ADABPO ENGINEERING\n");
while(1)
{
  printf("Please enter your ID: ");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  if(b==a[0])
  {
     printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Ah-Fong Wan!");
     break;
  }
  else if(b==a[1])
  {
     printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Aisac!");   
     break;
  }
  else if(b==a[2])    
  {
     printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Alsong!");          
     break;
   }
  else  if(b==a[3])
   {
     printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Ayassamy!");
     break;
    }
  else if(b==a[4])
  {
     printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Balkins!");   
     break;
   }
  else  if(b==a[5])
  {
     printf("Welcome Mr/Mrs Bilbo!");               
     break;
  }
  // ...

  else 
  {
     printf("Unable to identify,please try again!!\n");    
  }
}  
getch();
return 0;
}
```

break condition is used to come out of immediate loop which is while loop in  this case. while(1) indicates infinite looping condition and is used to go through all the options again till the user enters valid no. which matches the array elements.